# What does $A\subset B$ a.s. mean?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. Let $A$ and $B$ two sets. What $A\subset B$ almost surely mean ?

If $X$ and $Y$ are r.v. , then $X\leq Y$ a.s. or $X=Y$ a.s. mean that $$\mathbb P\{X\leq Y\}=1\quad \text{or}\quad \mathbb P\{X=Y\}=1.$$

But with sets (or event), I don't really see how to interpret $$\mathbb P(A\subset B)=1.$$
Is it the same as the usual inclusion ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it means $P(A\backslash B)=0$. Although I never heard of "almost sure" in this context.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. More generally I would say $A\setminus B\subseteq N\in\mathcal A$ such that $P(N)=0$. It is not for sure that $A\setminus B\in\mathcal A$ so $P(A\setminus B)$ might not exist.

Comment: Yes, it's a fair point.